# Phalcon 3 caching parsed template but not returning it

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I'm having trouble migrating from Phalcon 2.0.x to 3.1.1 - when I try to compile the template with Volt, the returned output is empty. The even more interesting thing is that the correctly parsed template (i.e. not empty) is stored in the cache folder, but it's not returned. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
$this->templateEngine->getView()->setVars($params);
                $this->templateEngine->getView()->start();
                $this->templateEngine->getView()->render(
                        $this->compiler->getOption('compiledPath'),
                        basename($compiledTemplateFile, $this->compiler->getOption('compiledExtension'))
                );
                $this->templateEngine->getView()->finish();

                return $this->templateEngine->getView()->getContent();
```

The same code works in Phalcon 2.0, running on PHP 5.6.25 (PHP version not changed, just using the newly compiled version of PhalconPHP). No errors are either displayed, nor logged in the error log. I'm open to suggestions, including how to debug if Phalcon encounters an error and that's why it doesn't return the output.

Answer (score 0):

I had a some problem.
empty template and content 
The problem was solved like this:

phalcon 2.x

```
 $this->view->pick('/admin/events/list');
```

phalcon 3.x

```
$this->view->pick('admin/events/list');
```

Not ordinary, but it works!

Comment: Thanks, but that (or more precisely, a similar approach to the render() method) doesn't seem to work for me :(